# Perform mouse click within requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I performed an POST method query and start parse,

>

```
resp = requests.post('http://TARGET_URL', headers=headers, cookies=cookies,data=query_param_str)
```

But How could I perform mouse click action `during the request session`

I must do the action in this request session.

any idea?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [**Selenium**](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/).

Comment: Also look at `urllib2` and `lxml`. If the page does not use JS, then scraping is incredibly fast using just these most simple libraries.

Comment: @KevinGuan but the previous step need to be done by Python requests because to fill those lots of params with selenium is  too painful and hard to automatic, some actions really hard to do on this page.

Comment: I think if you need click a button then requests can't do this. selenium is the best choice here.

Comment: Are you sure that you actually need to perform a mouse click? I would guess that there's an XHR request being made when you click that you could GET with requests instead.